# Electronics Lab - Not measuring voltage drop across resistor connected in series with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-design, series

I'm working on an RC circuits lab for school, and it stated to connect a circuit as follows: 15VAC in series with a 470-ohm resistor and 4.7uF capacitor and measure the voltage drop across the resistor and the capacitor and the total across both components. When set up, I individually measure no drop across the resistor and 15v drop across the capacitor. However, when measuring across both components, I get a 15V drop. I'm unsure why the capacitor is the only component measuring a drop, not the resistor. Other students measured 8V drop across the resistor and 7V drop across the capacitor.

Comment: Either your resistor is a dud, or you're actually working with DC instead of AC.

Comment: What frequency are you using? The voltage will divide approximately equally at 60 Hz. At much lower frequencies the cap voltage will be higher.

Comment: Hearth, when I remove the capacitor, the resistor measures the 15 v. This was part 2 of the lab. Part one I had the same 470 ohm resistor connected in series with a 1k ohm resistor and it worked fine with the distribution. when I took out the 1k ohm resistor and replace with the capacitor, that's where I ran into this. And the input it connected to a 15VAC on my breadboard. I have the Elenco XK-700 Trainer.

Comment: @Hearth Or the capacitor could be a dud. C.Harrison, have you tried replacing both of them with different ones to see if you get a reading?

Comment: If there is no voltage drop across the resistor that means no current is flowing through it, and therefore no current flowing through the capacitor either. Explanations for your findings include 1) your frequency is too low or DC (capacitors don't pass current at DC), or 2) you don't have a complete circuit (double check wiring from supply to resistor to capacitor back to supply), or 3) the capacitor is defective.

Comment: I will retest tomorrow with all new components and post the results.

Comment: 4) the capacitor is much smaller than you think it is - if it's 4.7nF for example then very little 60Hz current will flow through it.

Comment: sorry for late reply! I ended up ordering a new breadboard and just redid the circuit with new components as well. 470 ohm resistor, 4.7uF capacitor on 15 VAC. When measuring voltage drop across the resistor, it resulted in 9.9 V and the drop on the capacitor was 11.9V.  When measuring across both, I got a reading of 15.8V Does this seenm correct?

Comment: Yes, almost. The capacitor can be thought of as a frequency-dependent resistor with a value of 1 / (2 * 3.14 * C * f) ohms. So a 4.7uF cap has an impedance of 565 ohm at 60 Hz. With the same current flowing through both the cap and a 470 ohm resistor you would expect the voltage drop across the larger impedance, the capacitor in this case, to be a little larger, 565/470 larger to be precise, which is exactly what 11.9/9.9 is. The only mystery is it would seem your starting voltage is more like 22VAC. Measure that - don't trust what it says on AC adaptor (can be much higher with light load).

Comment: Oh right, the 9.9 + 11.9 don't add up to your total 15.8 because they are not in phase with each other. The RC filter shifts the phase of the signal across the cap.

Comment: td127- i actually made note on my lab report about that. It asked "Do the voltage drops across the resistor and capacitor add up to the total voltage applied to the circuit?" I replied that it did and I thought that it was due to it being out of phase with each other. This is the Elenco trainer and I plugged it into the 15VAC terminal so idk how it would be a starting voltage of 22VAC.

Comment: Also, thanks again for your help!!